# Quarkus container fails to start in Heroku due to symlinks that are changed by Heroku

Tags: java, docker, heroku, quarkus

I have the following Dockerfile.jvm that I built and deployed to Heroku.
Dockerfile,jvm:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-11:1.11

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/


EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"
```

I'm building my image using the following maven call:

```
./mvnw clean package\
  -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true\
  -Dquarkus.container-image.group=app-group\
  -Dquarkus.container-image.name=app-name\
  -Dquarkus.container-image.tag=latest
```

The image is created successfully.
When running the image on my local PC the app starts and everything is fine.

I then release my new image on Heroku (`heroku container:release web`)  and I'm seeing the following error in the Heroku logs:

```
2022-09-05T10:45:49.417696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/usr/local/s2i/run`
2022-09-05T10:45:50.352921+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the Java application using /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh ...
2022-09-05T10:45:50.485619+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO exec  java -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xms64m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -cp "." -jar /deployments/quarkus-run.jar
2022-09-05T10:45:50.540574+00:00 app[web.1]: /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh: line 245: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
2022-09-05T10:45:50.658843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2022-09-05T10:45:50.722618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Why is execution permission for `/usr/bin/java` denied when running on Heroku?

How can that be solved?

---

**Update:**

When checking the permissions on containers that I run in my PC I see the following:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 185 root 7339 Mar 28 09:45 /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 root 22 Mar 28 09:47 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

`/etc/alternatives/java` is a symlink that point to the java executable.

But on Heroku the permissions are being changed to the following:

```
-rwx------ 1 30176 dyno 7339 Mar 28 09:45 /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh
---------- 1 59598 dyno 0 Sep  5 17:11 /usr/bin/java
```

**Apparently, Heroku breaks symbolic links that point to other symbolic links.**

It's not clear what should be done to amend this behavior by Heroku,

Comment: I tried deploying the same container with `CMD ["ls", "-l", "/usr/bin/java"]` and noticed that Heroku has changed the permissions on the java binary to be `---------- 1 59598 dyno 0 Sep  5 17:11 /usr/bin/java` - not only that it had changed the group to dyno (which might be expected as they run the container under a different user) but they have apparently also changed rwx permissions to 000 .

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by editing the scripts in my container to bypass any symlink A (corrupt symlink) that should have pointed to symlink B.
In other words, I changed my scripts to point directly at symlink B.